# Reference value of previous row in same column

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have a data set which identifies separate tables through a column `Col1` where a `%T` row value indicates this is a new table (and the name is provided at `Col2`), and `%R` indicates this is a record within the table (and the value is provided at `Col2`).

A data set with two tables would look like this:

| Col1 | Col2 |
| --- | --- |
| %T | Table1 |
| %R | something |
| %R | else |
| %R | etc |
| %T | Table2 |
| %R | other value |
| %R | one more |
| %R | etc |

I want to be able to separate these tables. My plan is to calculate a new column where the table name would appear, then I can `Group By` this column and get `All`, which should return 2 subsets which I can then work with separately.

I am stuck at this step where I need to propagate the table name in all rows for which `Col1 = "%R"`. Ideally, I would add a step named `Added Custom Column` with the following formula:

```
= Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "TableName", each if [Col1] = "%T" then [Col2] else #"Added Custom Column"[TableName]{[Index]-1})
```

But this does not work because `#"Added Custom Column"` does not yet exist, and I understand this would be equivalent to generating some sort of circular reference.

In regular Excel I would insert a column before Col1 and do `=if(RC[1]="%T",RC[2],R[-1]C)`. How can I achieve this with Power Query?

Comment: Add a custom column with a formula like `if [Col1] = "%T" then [Col2] else null`.  Then just `FillDown` the custom column, and Group by it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment, given your data:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table7"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Col1", type text}, {"Col2", type text}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom", each if [Col1] = "%T" then [Col2] else null),
    #"Filled Down" = Table.FillDown(#"Added Custom",{"Custom"}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Filled Down", {"Custom"}, {
        {"all", each _, type table [Col1=nullable text, Col2=nullable text, Custom=text]}
        })
in
    #"Grouped Rows"
```

Will => the two grouped tables

If you don't want that first row (the one with the table name) to be in the subgroup table, merely change the aggregation to remove it:

```
{"all", each Table.RemoveFirstN(_,1), type table [Col1=nullable text, Col2=nullable text, Custom=text]}
```

Comment: Many thanks Ron, I just came to the same conclusion about `FillDown` moments ago. This resolves my problem 100%, but I would be curious to know - for future analyses - if there would be any other way to achieve this? In particular, is it possible somehow to compute a calculation based on the previous row value? `FillDown` would propagate but not allow to modify the propagated value; would the only solution be to then add another custom column where the calculation would be performed?

Comment: @Ama Your question is too broad to answer in other than generalities. Grouping is probably the most efficient way to accomplish this task. Yes, there are other ways to refer to a previous row: you can use an Index column; you can add a custom column offset by number of lookback rows you want to examine; you can use various `List` functions to create new, modified columns, etc.  Depends on exactly what you want to do.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. There is the possibility to add new columns and populate data by a set increment, such as `Val(N) = Val(N-1)+1` or `= Val(N-1)+2`. What if instead, for example, I wanted the value of row N to be something like `Val(N) = Val(N-1) ^ 2`, or `= Val(N-1) * 2 + Val(N-2)`, or even `ValThisCol(N) = Max(ValOtherCol(N-1), ValThisCol(N-1))`

Comment: @Ama Yes, that would be possible also.